# I want to find one user using regex from the text file which is in json like format. Find the user with regex and remove it with surrounding text

Tags: regex, shell-script, bash-scripting, text-processing

Find the user from the below text (highlighted `testUser`)

```
define name{

        name                            **testUser**

        aliasName                       Test User

        emailID                         test.user@test.com

        use                             not used

        }

define name{

        name                            testUser111
        aliasName                       Test User111
        emailID                         test.user111@test.com
        use                             not used
        }
```

After removing only above user(testUser) from the whole file, output would look like below:

```
define name{

        name                            testUser111

        aliasName                       Test User111

        emailID                         test.user111@test.com

        use                             not used
        }
```

I tried below regex, but it selects all the users from the file. I am new to  regex.

```
\bdefine name\s*\{\s*[\s\S]*?\s*}
```

I got to know the below answer `sed -i '/${DATA}/d' test.txt` -command would remove provided data from the file and update it.

Please suggest.

Comment: Java or shell-script or javascript or groovy? You have to choose one of them because regex are not the same flavour in all these languages.

Comment: okay, i would like to use shellscript. and after finding the right contact (i.e user), i need to remove it from the file using shellscript

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you want to get a full definition of let's say user with `name` `testUser` then this should work, for instance:

```
define name\s*{\s*name\s+testUser\b[^}]*}
```

It looks for `name` field and then matches `testUser` word separated with whitespaces right next to it. Then it goes for anything that's not a `}` and finishes on `}`

The easiest way to use it in Bash with multiline matching is probably Perl:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/define name\s*{\s*name\s+testUser\b[^}]*}//g" test.txt
```

The `-0777` switch specifies it should be treated as single line. It replaces the match(es) with blank (`//`) in substitution mode (`s/`).

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer. I understand, above regex will work to find the user from the file. AFter finding the user, I want to remove it using shellscript command (may be grep / rm -rf) from the file. Could you please guide ?

Comment: @Cdarji start by removing improper tags from your question as someone mentioned - if you want it to be shell, remove Java, Javascript and Groovy. Add system info instead - e.g. can it be PowerShell on Windows? Or do you prefer bash script on Linux? I'll adjust the answer then as the regex works more or less with everything, but the CLI command for removal will be different.

Comment: alright. Its done now.